# Calculate Projected Point location (x,y) on given line start(x,y) end(x,y)

Tags: python, numpy

If i have three points P1, P2, P3 with their coordinates(x,y)

P1(x,y) and P3(x,y) are coordinate of line(start, end) and P3 is a point need to be projected.

how can i find the coordinate of point r(x,y) which is projection of P3 over P1 and P2
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Projection of a point on line defined by 2 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232356/projection-of-a-point-on-line-defined-by-2-points)

Comment: No that is different and it use Microsoft.Maps.Location API, I am looking to solve it in Python and Numpy

Comment: It is trivial to port it to python - use your representation of point

Comment: I am checking here because i need it to be vectorized. i have thousands of points need to be projected. and i did not mentioned my points are 3d (x,y,z) for simplicity

Comment: In your question you say P1(x,y) and P3(x,y)  , which clearly defines @D points, not you say you need 3D solution. Make up your mind :)

Comment: Are you trying to project your point to a line or a segment (has clearly defined start/end)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution extends to points with any geometric dimensions (2D, 3D, 4D, ...). It assumes all points are one dimensional numpy arrays (or two dimensional with one dimension shape 1). I am not sure if you require the projection to fall onto line segment or the extension of segment so I include both. You can pick whichever fits your question the best:

```
#distance between p1 and p2
l2 = np.sum((p1-p2)**2)
if l2 == 0:
  print('p1 and p2 are the same points')

#The line extending the segment is parameterized as p1 + t (p2 - p1).
#The projection falls where t = [(p3-p1) . (p2-p1)] / |p2-p1|^2

#if you need the point to project on line extention connecting p1 and p2
t = np.sum((p3 - p1) * (p2 - p1)) / l2

#if you need to ignore if p3 does not project onto line segment
if t > 1 or t < 0:
  print('p3 does not project onto p1-p2 line segment')

#if you need the point to project on line segment between p1 and p2 or closest point of the line segment
t = max(0, min(1, np.sum((p3 - p1) * (p2 - p1)) / l2))

projection = p1 + t * (p2 - p1)
```

Comment: yes this is what i am looking for, Thank you so much

Comment: @MSallal You are welcome. If it solves your problem please accept the answer to help others find it useful. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Using first equation for t in my post results in projection on extended line/segment line which is essentially perpendicular to it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, would it be possible to link the mathematical foundation of this answer? I found several parametric line equations, but have not decided which one is more convenient for implementation

Answer (score 6):

Numpy code that works for both 2D and 3D (based on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/how-can-i-project-a-3d-point-onto-a-3d-line):

```
import numpy as np

def point_on_line(a, b, p):
    ap = p - a
    ab = b - a
    result = a + np.dot(ap, ab) / np.dot(ab, ab) * ab
    return result

A = np.array([2, 0])
B = np.array([4, 4])
P = np.array([1, 3])
projected = point_on_line(A, B, P)
print(projected)
```

**Update**

Plot:

```
A = np.array([ 10.5, 15.6 ])
B = np.array([ 2, 6 ])
P = np.array([ 18.561, -19.451])

projected = point_on_line(A, B, P) 
print(projected)
# [-3.35411076 -0.04699568]

plt.xlim(-20, 20)
plt.ylim(-20, 20)
plt.axis('equal')

x_values = [A[0], B[0]]
y_values = [A[1], B[1]]

plt.plot(B[0], B[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(A[0], A[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(P[0], P[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'b-')
plt.plot(projected[0], projected[1], 'rx')
```

**Update 2**

If you need the point to belong to the segment, you need to make a small amendment

```
def point_on_line(a, b, p):
    ap = p - a
    ab = b - a
    t = np.dot(ap, ab) / np.dot(ab, ab)
    # if you need the the closest point belonging to the segment
    t = max(0, min(1, t))
    result = a + t * ab
    return result
```

Comment: i tried this before, it is not showing the projected point check this notebook https://projected-msallal.notebooks.azure.com/j/notebooks/ProjectedPoint.ipynb

Comment: I took a look at your notebook, you have 2 errors: 1: you call projected = ClosestPointOnLine(A, P, B) while it needs to be projected = ClosestPointOnLine(A, B, P). 2>You plot in an incorrect way

Comment: how can we make it perpendicular on line

Comment: See update how to make it belong on the line. Note that accepted answer is basically the same algorithm using more  basic functions: `np.sum((p1-p2)**2)` is equal to `np.dot(ab, ab)` etc.

Comment: lol. this is exactly the same answer :D. It is also good to check for `ab != 0` to avoid throwing division by zero error.