# Perpendicular Projection of point onto line using GeoDjango

Tags: python, gis, postgis, geodjango

I have a point `C` and a Linestring `AB`, both with SRID `4326`. I'd like to find the perpendicular projection of `C` onto `B`, which would be point `D`.

[image]

I currently have a 2D implementation of this perpendicular projection using unit vectors. But it does not return the correct point on a world map (as it is 2D). Found here: [Perpendicular on a line segment from a given point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301001/perpendicular-on-a-line-segment-from-a-given-point)

I have thought of two ways to do this with PostGIS:

1) Create a line from `C` to point `E`, where `CE` is parallel to `AB`. Then rotate `CE` 90 degrees around `C` and find the intersection, which should be `D`.

2) Find a bearing and distance method similar to the Google Maps geometry library here (the `computeOffset` method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

How would I do this with the `GeoDjango` methods. It does not seem to expose the `ST_AZIMUTH` or `ST_ROTATE`?

It also seems like using raw SQL in `GeoDjango` would be an antipattern. But in this case, it seems like I need more granular control than what the `GeoDjango` API allows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of point and `LineString` closest point returned by `PostGIS` `ST_ClosestPoint` http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html will be an orthogonal projection of point onto `LineString`