# How to calculate x and y coordinates for a point which draws perpendicular to a line?

Tags: javascript

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301001/perpendicular-on-a-line-segment-from-a-given-point) except i want to calculate point c. I have point A, B and D. How can i calculate X and Y components of points C?

Comment: This is mathematics. Also I need some context

Comment: having points A,B and D from what i understand from what you have is a straight line, so having this point C come off of point D is fine, however you need a length to get any valid point from it

though the y location of C will be the same as D's with the X location being determinate of the length of the line you want

Comment: Suppose AB line have an angle t and i want  a point say D, out of the line which makes a line CD. Where AB is perpendicular to CD.